# R: Powercurve for single variable

Tags: r, lme4, effect, simulate

does anyone know how to plot a power curve for a single variable via the function `powerCurve` of the `simr` package? (`glmer` and `lmer` objects)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried saving the `powerCurve` object and calling `plot()` and it worked.

```
fit1 <- lmer(response ~ var1 + var2 + (1|subject), data)

powercurve_object <- powerCurve(fit1)

plot(powercurve_object)
```

The `powerCurve()` function only runs for a single variable, and by default it is the first variable in your model, so the code here would give you a powerCurve plot for `var1`. If you want to run `powerCurve()` on another variable in the model fit, you can use the `test` argument when you call `powerCurve()` (or refit the model with the variable you want to plot listed first).

Hope this helps.